# Effect Oracle Database migration from 11g to 12c on ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, oracle, database-migration, odp.net

I have an ASP.net application and we are using Oracle 11g data base. Our client is planning to migrate to 12c, do i need to add new Oracle.DataAccess reference to my ASP.net application or will it work with older version which is already available.

Also Do i need to install new version Oracle Data Provider for .net if data base is migrated?

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the version of ODP.NET you are using, as long as you are using version 11.2 or later.

Versions of ODP.NET back to 11.2 will work with databases up to version 12.2. There is no need to try to match the ODP.NET version and the database version unless you are trying to take advantage of a new database feature. (In the 12.2 database, this might include something like Sharding).